# Change TB Mega Menu Dropdown to Toggle

Tags: theming, navigation

I want to change [TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu)
Dropdown on hover to Toggle on click. I tried inserting attributes using this jQuery

```
$("li.dropdown.parent > a").attr("class", "dropdown-toggle");
$("li.dropdown.parent > a").attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
$("li.dropdown.parent > a").attr("aria-haspopup", "true");
$("li.dropdown.parent > a").attr("aria-expanded", "false");
```

But cannot work correctly. Toggle is working but hover dropdown is still active. Is there a better way to do it.

Comment: I am also looking for the same. If you find any solution please post it here.